# SSRS Total based on Expression Value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a total that is based on a calculation to provide Gross Weight.  Now before someone suggests (modify the SQL to give results and then total that in SSRS) this is coming from a dynamics AX query which i don't have access to.  This is my report

[image]

Which gives results

[image]

Total highlighted in red is wrong (it should be 18043.25 if you add up the lines).  Which i've done by right clicking on gross weight expression and gone 'Add Total'.

Expression for Gross Weight (at line level)

```
=SUM(Fields!qty.Value * (Fields!NetWeight.Value + Fields!TaraWeight.Value)) + IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value)
```

The Sum bit is pretty straightforward just summing netweight and taraweight but then needs to add the pallet weight which varies depending on whether it's a pallecon or not.  The total seems to be adding the `IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value`

part only once instead of evaluating for each line and summing.  I tried wrapping the expression in another SUM however i got around 23300 for gross weight which is way too high.  As I stated before I should be getting 18043.25.  How do you do a total based on a total expression of another column? Thanks!

*** UPDATE *** Total Expression Testing

```
(test1) =SUM(Fields!qty.Value * (Fields!NetWeight.Value + Fields!TaraWeight.Value)) + RunningValue(IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value), Sum, "Group1") = 23323.22

(test2) =RunningValue(SUM(Fields!qty.Value * (Fields!NetWeight.Value + Fields!TaraWeight.Value)) + IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value), SUM, "Group1") = 3267881.87

(test3) =RunningValue(Fields!qty.Value * (Fields!NetWeight.Value + Fields!TaraWeight.Value) + IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value), SUM, "Group1") = 23323.22
```

After much testing, I believe I have an issue somewhere on grouping... I think this should give me what i'm after as a total expression.  Please correct me if i'm wrong.

```
=SUM(Fields!qty.Value * (Fields!NetWeight.Value + Fields!TaraWeight.Value)) + RunningValue(IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value), SUM, "Group1") = 23323.21805
```

Which is too high.  I ran the expression on it's own which gave me about 33 per line total of 1056 so I have no idea where the extra is coming from...

*** FURTHER UPDATE ***

I think I've found the issue it's to do with this expression :

```
IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, (Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value))
```

This gives 33kg per line.

However `SUM(IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, (Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value)))`

in the total field gives 6336.  I should be getting 33 * 32 lines = 1056.

Where is the extra 5000 coming from?!?!?!?

Comment: That expression looks ok at first glance. Is it identical to the expression used in the individual rows for gross weight?

Comment: that is not the total expression.  that is the gross weight expression at the line level.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit. Something's not adding up (both literally and figuratively), since that expression should work if it's in the immediate parent group of those line items, which it looks like it is. Do you have any filters that you've set below the dataset level? (i.e. group or row-level?) At this point, I'd be looking at the raw data coming into your dataset as well. You could also try wrapping the expression for the total in =RunningValue([that expression], "[your group name here]")

Comment: Hi thanks for your help.  All I did was click on the expression (which I created) and go Add total to create the total expression.  However as I stated the part IIF(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon", Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value, Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value + Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value seems to only be evaluated once not summing this for every line.  I will try the runningtotal and see if that makes a difference!  It did cross my mind maybe i could use this, but never used it before...

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the expression in your report by using Calculated Fields in your dataset, so you can break the calculation into smaller parts to see what is going on? Are you able to provide some sample data?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment.  Do you mean just adding extra fields to the tablix to see the individual column values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my colleague has come up with an alternative solution.  Still not sure why the other one isn't working correctly but this works!

```
=SUM(Fields!qty.Value * (Fields!NetWeight.Value + Fields!TaraWeight.Value)) + (Sum(IIf(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon",1,0)) * Max(Fields!PalleconWeightKg.Value))+(CountDistinct(Fields!wMSPalletId2.Value) - Sum(IIf(Fields!palletTypeId.Value = "Pallecon",1,0))) * (Max(Fields!BluePalletWeightKg.Value) + Max(Fields!PackagingWeightKg.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses indicate your IIF statement should only be added once.

Simplifying your Field names for clarity shows me

```
=SUM ( 
      A * (
          B + C
     )
 ) + 
 IIF(
     D, E, F + G
 )
```

Or even more simply

```
SUM ( X ) + conditional
```

When it appears you want

```
SUM ( X + conditional )
```

Is this not the case?

Comment: No because the conditional is a pallet weight.  If you look at the lines it's per pallet which needs to be added once per line.  So I do believe I need to be doing SUM (X) + conditional at the LINE level and then total would be SUM(SUM(X)) + SUM(conditional) I believe.